# Compare variadic arguments by value

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Is there a way to compare the values of each type of a variadic template?

```
template<typename... S>
class Signature {
    // this is not valid syntax
    S... values;

    bool equals(S... s) {
        // this is not either
        bool eq = true;
        eq &= s... &= values...;
        return eq;
    }
};
```

Example:

```
Signature<int, bool> s(5, true);
s.equals(5, true); // should result in 1
```

Comment: c++11, c++14 or c++17?

Comment: Does not matter (, but c++11 would be nice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
S... values;
```

is ill-formed. You cannot have a pack declaration like that (unfortunately). You have to put all the values in something, like:

```
std::tuple<S...> values;
```

And once you do that, comparing them is simple. Just use `==`:

```
template<typename... S>
struct Signature {
    std::tuple<S...> values;

    bool equals(Signature<S...> const& rhs) const {
        return values == rhs.values;
    }

    bool equals(S const&... rhs) const {
        // forward here to produce a tuple<S const&...> and avoid an unnecessary copy
        return values == std::forward_as_tuple(rhs...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, that is simple! Why do you name your variables `rhs`? I am asking just for interest.

Comment: @PaulProgrammerNoob Just cause it's on the right-hand-side of equals.

Answer (score 2):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) we simply do:

```
std::tuple<S...> values;
bool equals(S const&...s) const {
  return std::apply([&](S const&... values){
    return ((values==s)&&...);
  }, values);
}
```

as `S... values;` is not legal.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), the best way is to write your own `apply`:

```
namespace details{
  template<std::size_t...Is, class F, class Tuple>
  decltype(auto) apply(std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Tuple&&t){
    using std::get;
    return std::forward<F>(f)( get<Is>( std::forward<Tuple>(t) )... );
  }
}
template<class F, class Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply( F&& f, Tuple&& tuple )
  using dT=std::decay_t<Tuple>;
  auto size=std::tuple_size<dT>{};
  return details::apply( std::make_index_sequence<size>{}, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) );
}
```

and put it in `namespace notstd`.  You also need to rrplace the fold:

```
return ((values==s)&&...);
```

with

```
bool r = true;
using discard=int[];
(void)discard{0,(void(
  r = r && (values==s)
),0)...};
return r;
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you'll need to replace the `decltype(auto)` with trailing return types and implement your own index sequence code.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem I can see is ... what is

```
S ... values;
```

in your class?

That isn't C++, as far I know.

I suppose you can save your values in a `std::tuple`

```
std::tuple<S...> value;
```

so (if you don't want put your `s` in a `std::tuple` and compare the tuples, that is simple but isn't funny) the real problem in your code is connected with the use of the tuple.

I propose the following solution in C++17, based on the new fold expression

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Signature
 {    
   std::tuple<Ts...> values;

   Signature (Ts && ... ts) : values { std::forward<Ts>(ts) ... }
    { }

   template <std::size_t ... Is>
   bool equalsH (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, Ts const & ... ts)
    { return ((ts == std::get<Is>(values)) && ... ); }

   bool equals (Ts const & ... ts)
    { return equalsH(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}, ts...); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Signature<int, bool> s { 5, true };

   std::cout << s.equals(5, true) << std::endl;  // print 1
   std::cout << s.equals(5, false) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << s.equals(6, false) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << s.equals(6, true) << std::endl;  // print 0
 }
```

In C++14 you can't use fold expression like in C++17 so you have to modify the helper function (`equalH()`); I propose the following

```
   template <std::size_t ... Is>
   bool equalsH (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, Ts const & ... ts)
    { 
      using unused = int[];

      bool ret { true };

      (void)unused { 0, (void(ret &= (ts == std::get<Is>(values))), 0) ... };

      return ret;
    }
```

Unfortunately `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` are available only starting from C++14, so the preceding example doesn't work in C++11; but create a substitute of `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` isn't difficult and, if you want it, you can use the tuple-compare solution

```
bool equals (Ts && ... ts)
 { return values == std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<Ts>(ts) ... ); }
```